# Limitation join children with Firebase Functions

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a multiplayer game. 2 Players can play each other. A User creates room it's ok. However if 2 or more other users join this room at the same time, there will be a big problem. I try to prevent this situation below codes.

Function Code:

```
exports.sinirla = functions.database.ref('/AllUsers/{id}')
    .onWrite(event => {
        const orginalValue = event.data.numChildren();
        if (orginalValue == 2) {
            return event.data.ref.child('userCount').set(1);
        } else if (orginalValue == 3) {
            return event.data.ref.child('userCount').set(2);
        } else {
            return
        }
    });
```

Firebase Tree:

[image: User A Create room and waiting for player now]

Finally Join Game code Below:

```
userFirstLoginRef
    .child("AllUsers")
    .queryOrdered(byChild: "userCount")
    .queryEqual(toValue: 1)
    .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapp) in
        if(snapp.exists()){
            let odaAdi = snapp.children.allObjects[0] as! DataSnapshot
            let snappKeyName = odaAdi.key
            self.userFirstLoginRef
                .child("AllUsers")
                .child(snappKeyName)
                .child(self.oyuncuID)
                .setValue(["ID":self.oyuncuID,"point":100])
        } else {
            self.createRoom()
        }
    }) { (error) in
        print(error)
    }
```

Users Only join a room if the room's "usercount" value is 1. Firebase functions code will update "usercount" value to 2, when the user joins the created room. However,if 2 or more users click join at the same time, all of them can join in the same room. So I want to limit room capacity is 2. Can Firebase cloud functions block this situation?

Comment: check out https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/limit-children

Comment: I checked it. However, in above link, 3.user can join after that removed from a parent. I want to block at the beginning if it is possible.